# Authorization policies in blazor server side

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I'm trying to find docs on the blazor server side equivalent of asp.net core authorization policies, but can't seem to find anything.

Can someone tell me what the mechanism is for authorization in blazor server side?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No authentication and authorization for Blazor exist right now. The Asp.Net team is currently working on it...
You may read here the whole story: https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/4048

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 3):

The latest preview -6 of .NET Core 3 has introduced authentication and authorization for server-side Blazor.
Refer to https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/asp-net-core-and-blazor-updates-in-net-core-3-0-preview-6/
I have also created an application which implements Google authentication in a Blazor app.
You can check it at https://github.com/AnkitSharma-007/Google-Authentication-with-server-side-Blazor

Answer (score 0):

With .NET Core 3.1 having been in production now for several months, there are a lot of problems with the Server-Side use of ASP.NET Core Identity.

Here is an excellent post I came across a couple of days ago, and has helped me implement Authentication and Authorisation in Blazor Server...

[Blazor Server Identity Interop](https://github.com/bdnts/BlazorServerIdentityInterop)